# Invoke an api gateway from an aws lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I try to invoke an api gateway from an aws lambda, which is triggered by a sqs queue. And my api gateway call another lambda function to get some informations.

But when i send a message from my sqs queue, lambda is correctly executed but the invocation of my api gaetway is not executed.

My code below :

```
var https = require('https');
const URL = process.env.API_GATEWAY_URL;

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

  console.log("hello");

  https.get(URL, function (result) {
      console.log('Success, with: ' + result.statusCode);
      context.done(null);
  }).on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error, with: ' + err.message);
      context.done("Failed");
  });

};
```

**And here are the logs I have in cloudwatch:**

START RequestId: 4eeccd03-b7d2-5efc-aedb-8c3a14411101 Version: $LATEST
2020-04-21T13:14:01.524Z 4eeccd03-b7d2-5efc-aedb-8c3a14411101 INFO hello 
END RequestId: 4eeccd03-b7d2-5efc-aedb-8c3a14411101

**But i expect something like that:**

START RequestId: 4eeccd03-b7d2-5efc-aedb-8c3a14411101 Version: $LATEST 
2020-04-21T13:14:01.524Z 4eeccd03-b7d2-5efc-aedb-8c3a14411101 INFO hello
2020-04-21T13:14:01.524Z 4eeccd03-b7d2-5efc-aedb-8c3a14411101 Success, with: 200 
END RequestId: 4eeccd03-b7d2-5efc-aedb-8c3a14411101

**Or:**

START RequestId: 4eeccd03-b7d2-5efc-aedb-8c3a14411101 Version: $LATEST 
2020-04-21T13:14:01.524Z 4eeccd03-b7d2-5efc-aedb-8c3a14411101 INFO hello 
2020-04-21T13:14:01.524Z 4eeccd03-b7d2-5efc-aedb-8c3a14411101 Error, with : message_error 
END RequestId: 4eeccd03-b7d2-5efc-aedb-8c3a14411101

And all my lambda are in the same VPC.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you didn't use URL constant while making a request ?

Comment: little mistake when I wrote the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed the newer async function handler with the older context/callback pattern.

If you want to use the older style, then remove the `async` function decorator.

If you want to use the newer (preferred) style, then change your code to return a promise, for example:

```
const https = require('https');
const URL = 'https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees';

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(URL,(res) => {
            let body = "";

            res.on("data", (chunk) => {
                body += chunk;
            });

            res.on("end", () => {
                console.log(body);
                resolve(body);
            });

        }).on("error", (error) => {
            reject(error);
        });  

    });
};
```

And make the GET request to the correct URL, of course.

Comment: Your use of https.get also appears to be incorrect so I have updated that part of the answer to use data/end handlers, but it's secondary. I've included a standard REST API endpoint (`https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee`) so you can test this against a valid endpoint, rather than against your URL.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just tested your code with your endpoint and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: One thing that would really help here would be rather than saying "it doesn't work" repeatedly, actually provide symptoms of the failure you are seeing. Does it fail with an error code? An exception? Does the get request time out? Does it work but yield the wrong result? Something else? This code works fine in Lambda, outside of VPC so I am going to guess at this point that you are running in VPC, have incorrectly configured your networking, and the `https.get` call times out. But, again, that's guessing, because we are light on good information here.

Comment: You are right indeed. So it does not fail with error code, no exception, the request does not expire otherwise I will have a timeout. The code works well when I test it locally, I manage to get the API response. And all the lambda code works fine except the code where I execute the https.get request.

Comment: You need to do very specific things when configuring Lambda to run in a VPC. If you want it to be able to communicate with the internet, for example, then the Lambda function needs to be in a private subnet, and that subnet needs a default route to a NAT in a public subnet, and the public subnet requires an IGW.  If you want it to reach other, private endpoints then it must have a network route to those endpoints. Or, deploy it outside of VPC, of course, assuming that meets your requirements.

Comment: I want to reach other, my endpoint is an api gateway. But i don't know how can i check if i have a network route to this endpoint. Can you explain to me how could i do that?

Comment: If the API gateway endpoint is public then your Lambda needs a route to the internet (per above). If it’s private then search for API Gateway private endpoints.

Comment: I change some configs, and now i can execute the request. but i have an error : Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN.

Comment: I think your original problem is fixed. i think you are now onto a new problem, which is the networking of your Lambda function. You should read the AWS docs for how to set this up correctly, and open up a new problem if you aren't able to correct it. I would guess that your Lambda function cannot resolve names via DNS.