APIGateway not posting to connections
I am building a chat app and my only constraint is that the other person cant connect to the websocket directly, instead he answers with a POST webhook, which then updates the database, which then invoke a method, which then sends a webscoket connection that message.
So I have 2 APIGateways, one for the REST and one for the WebSocket.
when connecting 2 client using the wss then both send and recive the messages, postToConnection works as expected.
But when trying to get a referennce to the websocket apigateway and posting from the webhook invocation, nothing happens, no error, no message, nada.
i have logs on every line and the last log logged is the one before "postToConnection"
My lambda function has a source permission to the gateway with
arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*/@connections/*
and action Allow: execute-api:ManageConnections
what am I doing wrong?
I tried to send a message to the connected clients using postToConnection, i expected them to receive that message, but nothing happend, no log no message no idea.

After much struggle, I finally understood what was going on.
I was so sure that the issue was a permission issue of some sort, that after reading this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/61348783/6013703
I saw that an async function in my code, was not awaited properly and that was my problem.
